# Lazy initialization of singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I'm wondering why the 2nd variant is considered more lazy, that he first.

1.

```
public class Singleton {
        private static Singleton singleton=new Singleton();
    
        private Singleton(){}
    
        static public Singleton getInstance(){
            return singleton;
        }
    }
```

The singleton above is initialized when the class is loaded, that is when getInstance() is called. Because classes are loaded when they are required. It's not loaded before `getInstance()` call.  Is that correct?

But the sinleton below is also initialized  when getInstance() is called. So can't understand the benefits of the 2nd variant:

2.

```
public class SingletonWithHolder {

    private SingletonWithHolder() {
    }

    public static SingletonWithHolder getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private final static SingletonWithHolder instance = new SingletonWithHolder();
    }

   
}
```

Comment: No. I suspect there must be a case when Singleton is loaded before getInstance() call, otherwise 2nd variant would be useless. But what is that case?

Comment: The point is that `Holder` is used only by `getInstance()` so `Holder` is loaded the first time when `getInstance()` is executed.

Comment: And when Singleton is loaded  the first time?

Comment: How can `Singleton`  be used without it's  `getInstance()`?

Comment: For example `Singleton.class.getName();`. There are plenty of ways the class can be loaded without calling `getInstance()`.

Comment: Yes, some static Singleton's constant may be used somewhere, for example...

Comment: @Kayaman, could you give some other ways?

Comment: @Ekaterina `Class.forName("yourpackage.Singleton")` is one other example

Comment: @f1sh a good example, since it's very plausible that top level classes would be iterated reflectively through some mechanism (e.g. to observe annotations or something similar), but their inner classes wouldn't.

Comment: Your first code does not allow access to the singleton. How do you get a singleton?

Comment: @sadetaosa Why? Using getInstance()

Comment: It's an instance method.  It can only be called after getting a singleton.

Comment: @sadetaosa That's right, it's a mistake. I meant static. This is now fixed.